# How to match node labels using OR?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
match (p:Product {id:'5116003'})-[r]->(o:Attributes|ExtraAttribute) return p, o
```

How to match two possible node labels in such a query?

Per cybersam's suggestion, I changed to the follwoing:

```
MATCH (p:Product {id:'5116003'})-[r]->(o) 
WHERE o:Attributes OR o:ExtraAttributes
**WHERE any(key in keys(o) WHERE toLower(key) contains 'weight')** 
return o
```

Now I need to add the 2nd 'where' clause. How to modify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two single-label forms of your query:

```
MATCH (p:Product {id:'5116003'})-->(o:Attributes) RETURN p, o;

MATCH (p:Product {id:'5116003'})-->(o) WHERE o:Attributes RETURN p, o;
```

produce the same execution plan, as follows (I assume that there is an index on `:Product(id)`):

```
+-----------------+----------------+------+---------+------------------+--------------+
| Operator        | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Variables        | Other        |
+-----------------+----------------+------+---------+------------------+--------------+
| +ProduceResults |              0 |    0 |       0 | o, p             | p, o         |
| |               +----------------+------+---------+------------------+--------------+
| +Filter         |              0 |    0 |       0 | anon[33], o, p   | o:Attributes |
| |               +----------------+------+---------+------------------+--------------+
| +Expand(All)    |              0 |    0 |       0 | anon[33], o -- p | (p)-->(o)    |
| |               +----------------+------+---------+------------------+--------------+
| +NodeIndexSeek  |              0 |    0 |       1 | p                | :Product(id) |
+-----------------+----------------+------+---------+------------------+--------------+
```

This two-label form of the second query above:

```
MATCH (p:Product {id:'5116003'})-->(o) WHERE o:Attributes OR o: ExtraAttribute RETURN p, o;
```

produces an execution plan that is very similar (and therefore probably not much more expensive):

```
+-----------------+----------------+------+---------+------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Operator        | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Variables        | Other                               |
+-----------------+----------------+------+---------+------------------+-------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults |              0 |    0 |       0 | o, p             | p, o                                |
| |               +----------------+------+---------+------------------+-------------------------------------+
| +Filter         |              0 |    0 |       0 | anon[33], o, p   | Ors(o:Attributes, o:ExtraAttribute) |
| |               +----------------+------+---------+------------------+-------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)    |              0 |    0 |       0 | anon[33], o -- p | (p)-->(o)                           |
| |               +----------------+------+---------+------------------+-------------------------------------+
| +NodeIndexSeek  |              0 |    0 |       1 | p                | :Product(id)                        |
+-----------------+----------------+------+---------+------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

*By the way, the first query in the answer by @BrunoPeres has a similar execution plan as well, but the `Filter` operation is very different. It is not clear which would be faster.*

[UPDATE]

To answer your updated question: since you cannot have 2 back-to-back `WHERE` clauses, you can just add more terms to the already existing `WHERE` clause, like so:

```
MATCH (p:Product {id:'5116003'})-[r]->(o)
WHERE
  (o:Attributes OR o:ExtraAttributes) AND
  ANY(key in KEYS(o) WHERE TOLOWER(key) CONTAINS 'weight')
RETURN o;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [any()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-any) function:

```
match (p:Product {id:'5116003'})-[r]->(o)
where any (label in labels(o) where label in ['Attributes', 'ExtraAttribute'])
return p, o
```

Also, if you have [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures), you can use `apoc.path.expand` path expander procedure that expands from start node following the given relationships from min to max-level adhering to the label filters.

```
match (p:Product {id:'5116003'})
call apoc.path.expand(p, null,"+Attributes|ExtraAttribute",0,1) yield path
with nodes(path) as nodes
// return p and o nodes
return nodes[0], nodes[1]
```

[See more here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths).

Comment: The 2nd seems more efficient. What does 'path' return?  Can it return the 'o' node directly?

Comment: @user697911 `return path` returns the entire path. To return `p` and `o`, please see my edit.

Comment: My current query has lot of constraints like this: WHERE any(key in keys(o) WHERE toLower(key) contains '" + attrKey + "') " where attrKey or attrValue is variable. Is that possible to add similar constraints to the above query using 'apoc'?

Comment: @user697911 I'm not think so, since path expanders works based only on labels and relationship types. But I think it is a good question. Maybe you should make a new question about it...